# Bootstrap right-align inline <ul>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to find a solution to right-align my content for my container which is holding an inline un-ordered list. The issue that I'm having is that my list contains mixed content (text, links and icons).

```
    <!-- Header -->
<div class="container">
  <div id="intro" class="text-right">
    <ul class="list-inline">
      <li><a href="directions.php">5420 Bond Road, Louisville, MS 39339</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Nav Bar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">MCBC Louisville</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You can use `.text-right` to parent element of inline element

Comment: Without the full context, most proposed answers will be a lucky pick. Can you provide a working example, a code snippet and explain what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
<ul class="text-right list-inline">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "pull-right" class. It's default class of bootstrap and by this you can pull the text or your content to the right side easily.

here is how you can add the class:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="intro" class="pull-right">
    <ul class="list-inline">
      <li><a href="directions.php">Address Goes Here</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add bootstrap class 'text-right' on "intro" div like below:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="intro" class="text-right">
    <ul class="list-inline">
      <li><a href="directions.php">Address Goes Here</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did this, but the text is still positioned to the left. I have a Nav Bar directly beneath this container, I'm not sure if that's conflicting with it since everyone is suggesting that text-right should fix the issue. I'll add alittle extra code.

Comment: @user2019725 yes please add more code that you think conflict with this

Comment: Actually your navigation bar is set to position fixed, and your inline list is hide beside the navigation, but the text alignment is rigth, as you can see in the image link: https://ibb.co/ddPjtv

Comment: Here is what I'd like to accomplish. [link]https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1OAkgTROsntJinOJkUkPwyKDZJHHc3Sgoeh2Q4MxDQCw/edit?usp=sharing[/link]

Answer (score 0):

```
**add inline style float:right**


 <div class="container">
 <div id="intro" class="text-right" style="float:right">
 <ul class="list-inline">
  <li><a href="directions.php">Address Goes Here</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

   </li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>  
   </a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the way I've addressed this issue is I just took the content from the "intro" id and simply placed it on the nav-bar right aligned that was a much easier solution. I would have preferred to have a container above the navbar with right-aligned content, but I tried everything that was suggested here to no avail. I appreciate everyone's responses, you folks are amazing.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try this**
 <ul class="text-right list-inline d-block">
        <li><a href="directions.php">5420 Bond Road, Louisville, MS 39339</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: How is that different from other answers posted for this question? please add also an explanation to your answer